# readHTMLTable creates extra rows with null variables

Tags: r

I am trying to read a table from html file. I did it in following way:

```
mnydata = "file:///D:/Mampi/EastSinghbhum_updated/Treasury/TREASURY_DATA_EAST_SINGHBHUM/GHATSHILA_TREASURY_DATA/GHATSHILA_2016-17/GTSDAD001.html"
data2 <- readHTMLTable(mnydata, which = 2)
```

The command produces extra rows with null values. How to solve the problem?

[image: Image of the data set is attached]

Thanks,
Mampi

Comment: Please do not use images to present your data; use `dput(head(yourDataframe, 10))` and copy the output in your question!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Images are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing.  You've likely been on SO before and seen good questions. This is not a good question. You have not provided a reproducible example. You have not provided data. You have likely not read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info nor any of the links there pertaining to creating good questions. Please respect the time you're getting _for free_ from SO contributors and help them help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read here about the difference of [NULL vs. NA](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/) so you can use the names correctly.

```
IND <- apply(data2, 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))

data2[IND,]
```

---

So this approach uses `apply` with `margin = 1` (row-wise) to give you index of all **NON**-(all)-NA-rows.